# firebase nested query, slow response

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I want to query the firebase depending on the value received by the first query. So in a way it's going to be a nested query. The snapshot gives me a list values which needs to be run on `forEach` query.

I have written the query but it seems to be slow as the response shown on the UI is slow.

How can I make the query faster or if it is a UI problem then how to fix it?

Database Structure:

```
App:
  bar:
    barKey:
      liquors:
        liquorTypes(Vodka):
          liquorName:
            details

  liquorInfo:
    liquorName:
      details
```

Following is my query:

```js
getLiquorList = (liquorTypes, barKey) => {
  firebase.database().ref(`/bar/${barKey}/liquors/${liquorTypes}/`).once('value', snapshot => {
    const result = []

    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      firebase.database().ref(`/liquorInfo/${childSnapshot.key}`).on('value', userSnap => {
        result.push({
          key: userSnap.key,
          image: userSnap.val().imageURL,
          info: userSnap.val().info,
          name: childSnapshot.key,
          price: childSnapshot.val(),
        })

        this.setState({
          liquorList: result,
        })
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is the question? Do you want to make this function faster? Do you want to change your structure to be more efficient? Do you want to know if this is a database or UI problem? Or maybe you want to know what flavour of tea is best to drink while you wait? (The last one is supposed to be a joke)

Comment: @AndréKool I'm trying to make the function/query faster and if it's a UI problem then how to fix that?

Comment: If it is not UI problem,
There are two ways.
1. You can change database structure for your requirements.
2. Fetch all data from both paths, and loop over that data to grab your set of results.

Comment: @TusharSheth I need data from first path to fetch data from another path. I can store the needed data in the first path but that will increase the redundancy.

Comment: @AdarshSingh In no-sql redundancy is common thing and expected in some cases. You will have to consider about only read operation. Because read operation frequency will be very high then write operation.

Comment: @TusharSheth I know that but in this case there 2 different field which I'm storing it in different path, if I won't do that it will be stored like few 100s of times.

Comment: If that is the case, you will have to store data in a single place. It will be easy to update.

Comment: Fetching the data from multiple locations like this is not necessarily slow. Did you measure where your performance problem comes from? If you don't yet know whether it stems from loading the data, or from updating the UI, figuring *that* out should be your first priority. Anything else is [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: @AdarshSingh did you get solution for this problem? I'm facing same problem